# Jquery flickering background image

Tags: jquery, image, select

I have 2 questions regarding Jquery and a background image. I have a simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Dreamweaver test</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
<div id="container">
<div id="inner">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css:

```
     @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {margin:0;padding:0}
/* mac hide \*/
html,body{height:100%;width:100%;}
/* end hide */
body { 
background-color: black;
text-align:center;
min-height:468px;/* for good browsers*/
min-width:552px;/* for good browsers*/
}
#outer{
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:table;
vertical-align:middle;
}
#container {
text-align: center;
position:relative;
vertical-align:middle;
display:table-cell;
height: 468px;
} 
#inner {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
text-align: center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-image: url(mainpage.jpg);
}
```

As you can see i have a background image for the inner div and what I want is the following:

I have created another image called mainpageflickering.jpg whichs is slightly different. I want that image to flicker (like a broken lamp) and I think it is possible to do that with jQuery, but I dont know how. So these are my 2 questions:

How can I tell jQuery to use the background image to change?
How can I tell jQuery to flicker (example: 2 seconds normal image, 1 second of flickering, 2 seconds normal image, 1 second of flickering(everytime))?

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iyotum/1/edit)**</kbd>

jQ:

```
var $FlickImg = $('#inner img'), c = 0;

(function loop(){
  var time = ~~(Math.random()*600) + 1;
  $FlickImg.delay( time ).fadeTo(30, ++c%2, loop);
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="inner">
  <img src="image.jpg">  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#inner{
  background: url(backgroundImage.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, do you know if its possible to use more images , so instead of 1 image covering the original lets say 3 or 4? (beginner in jQuery)